# Set "--allow-script-in-comments" to JavaDoc in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I want to include javascript in my javadoc, so I added `<script src="###"></script>` like below:

```
javadoc {
    options.header = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://####.js\"></script>"
}
```

in my `build.gradle` file.

But when I was trying to generate javadoc, gradle aborts the build with an error message:

> 1 error
>
> javadoc: error - Argument for -header contains JavaScript.
>
> Use --allow-script-in-comments to allow use of JavaScript.
>
> :javadoc FAILED

But I can't find how to set `--allow-script-in-comments` in `build.gradle`. Help me plz.

Comment: `option.addStringOption('--allow-script-in-comments')` has to be set for the JavaDoc Gradle

Comment: @Nico Thanks for your advise. But I can't find `option` and of coursely, `addStringOption()` within `javadoc{ ... }` clause. I can access `options`, not `option` but it does not have `addStringOption()` method.

Comment: @Nico meant `options` I guess, it does contain the method https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/CoreJavadocOptions.html#addStringOption(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javadoc gradle task do 
`options.addBooleanOption("-allow-script-in-comments",true)`